# How to predict if a transaction will succeed or fail while its in mempool?

Tags: pancakeswap, bscscan

I am working on frontrunning code for bot.
The script found some target transaction as victim for frontrunning but this transaction mostly fails.
So is there any way we can predict if a transaction is going to succeed and fail while its in mempool.
Normally the error when transaction fail is “Insufficient Output Amount”.
This is for pancakeswap and binance smart chain.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get an answer on how to track front-running transaction on mempool?

Answer (score 0):

You can know whether the transaction fails or not without signing the transaction.

It is by using the STATICCALL.

You can use the STATICCALL, a low level function to simulate the transaction. It is something like run-time check the outcome of a transaction without actually signing a transaction.

[Sending Static Calls to a Smart Contract With Ethers.js](https://betterprogramming.pub/sending-static-calls-to-a-smart-contract-with-ethers-js-e2b4ceccc9ab)
.

This article can help you.

Tell me if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I did checked STATICCALL article just want to know if this can predict “Insufficient Output Amount”

Comment: Insufficient Output Amount, the error you are refering to will come when the voltality of a token is too high. If you are swapping A token to B token in 1:1 ratio and because of price voltality, the price ratio might change to 1:0.9. In that case, previously shown amount for example 100 A tokens to 100 B tokens might change to 100 A tokens to 90 B tokens. However, before the price change, they promised you 100 A tokens for 100 B tokens. That is when this error would come. Or in case of low liquidity in the pool.

Comment: And yes, you can predict the error as long as you track the pancakeswap pool or write a smart contract that tracks the pool and use static call for that function.

But just know, when the price is too volatile, the result of a transaction may change the matter of seconds.

Comment: Can i contact you by other mode to discuss further

Comment: If you have discord accout, you can drop your discord ID here. I will contact you.

Comment: Discord - psilmana

Comment: The ID format will be like psilmana_#<Number>

Comment: Are you available now